# My bootstrap-responsive.min.css file is conflicting with my pop-up menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project that has a pop-up menu when the user clicks a link in the menu bar but it always conflict with the **bootstrap-responsive.min.css**, file making my menu bar not clickable. 
How do I resolve it? This is my code

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dashboard</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600"   rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/pages/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
       <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </a>
       <div class="nav-collapse">
        <a href="index.php">
          <img src="../images/logo2.png" alt="Grace">
        </a>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="icon-cog"></i> Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="account.php">My Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="pop.php">Fly</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="icon-user"></i><?php echo $userRow['L_name']; echo ' '. $userRow['F_name']; echo ' '. $userRow['O_name']; ?> <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="user_profile.php">Profile</a></li>
               <a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
          <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse --> 
      </div>
      <!-- /container --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /navbar-inner --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /navbar -->
  <div class="subnavbar">
    <div class="subnavbar-inner">
       <div class="container">
        <ul class="mainnav">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="index.php"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i><span>Dashboard</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="user_profile.php"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i><span>My Profile</span> </a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="referrals.php"><i class="icon-facetime-video"></i><span>My Referrals</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bitcoin_donate_action"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><span>Provide Help</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bitcoin_gethelp_action"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i><span>Get Help</span> </a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-long-arrow-down"></i><span>My Accounts</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="Transaction_Board.php">My Transaction</a></li>
              <li><a href="pop.php">Prove of Payment</a></li>
              <li><a href="mywallet.php">My Wallet</a></li>
              <li><a href="../users_testimonials.php">Testimony</a></li>
              <li><a href="logout.php?logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```